# global variables not able to transfer values python

Tags: python, global-variables

I am new to python and trying to use Global variables were I can transfer values between two files **test1.py** and **test2.py** through an intermediate file **global_var.py** . I was able to put together these from what I read in few stackoverflow questions and demos. But I am not sure if am doing it write cuz its not working. Please tell me where am going wrong

global_var.py

```
    key_gen = []
    def init():
         global key_gen
```

test1.py

```
    import global_var
    global_var.init()
    global_var.key_gen = [1,2,3]
```

test2.py

```
    import global_var
    k = global_var.key_gen
    print k
```

However, the print doesn't give [1,2,3]. It instead gives [ ]. Can you please tell me how can I get this right? Thanks in advance

Edit : If I remove this statement

```
    key_gen = []
```

from **global_var.py** and run the same code again, I do not get any error while executing **test1.py** but when I run **test2.py** I get the following error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test2.py", line 3, in <module>
   k = global_var.key_gen
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'key_gen'
```

I am not able to completely understand why this is happening.

Comment: The `init()` function in `global_var` is entirely redundant. The `global` keyword only affects how a name is treated *in that function*, at compile time. You don't need the function here, you don't need to call it.

Comment: Are you executing `test1.py` and `test2.py` separately? If so, then no, module globals do not *persist*; they are not written to disk when one Python interpreter process changes it.

Comment: yes. I am executing them separately. how else can I achieve what I am trying to do? @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood something about the *lifetime* of module globals. Altering state in the Python interpreter is *not* persisted to disk. Changing `global_var.key_gen` from a script does not result in that change being saved when the interpreter exits again.

You'll have to *write changes to disk* explicitly. There are *many* options to choose from there; you could write the list to disk using [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (with a file object opened first), or you could use the [`shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) to create a dictionary whose contents are automatically persisted to disk.

Comment: Even Pickle can be used in this case to have object.

Comment: @New_User123: I wasn't going to create an exhaustive list. Note that `shelve` uses `pickle` under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

here you run separately  test1.py and test2.py file . if you use multiple class and multiple function in single file means u can change the global value or set the global value..u can assign a value to key_gen while u are running test1.py file after that keygen_value are reset. when u run test2.py file u can get only empty value because python interpreters stored the value in buffer.see the below sample

```
key_gen=0
class test1:
  def hai(self):
    global key_gen
    key_gen=10
    print  key_gen

class test2:
  def hai1(self):
     global key_gen
     print key_gen


instance1=test1()
instance1.hai()
instance2=test2()
instance2.hai1()
```